# Do I need to check readonly disks on boot?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, fsck, read-only

Every x startups, fsck will scan the disks for errors. This takes a very long time for large Disks.

Suppose I made a harddisk read-only with the command `sudo tune2fs -O read-only /dev/sdXY`.
Are those File system checks still required?

Comment: Yes, because the current system does not know the history of the disk (where was it when the power was OFF?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disk can still corrupt, even in read only mode. Hence, disks should be regularly checked.